# Create a new, previously non-existent, file in Firebase - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm in the progress of making an iOS app which allows the user to create HTML, CSS and JavaScript websites from their phone.

The app is eventually going to be paired to a website and a macOS application, therefore, I am saving everything to the cloud so projects can be accessed from anywhere.

The problem I'm facing, is that I can't find a way to create a brand new file inside of Firebase, only upload an existing file like a photo.

I would like to create HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files, without saving them to the device.

Thank you for your time! I appreciate any help.

Comment: First, Firebase technology (sadly) does not support macOS so you should switch to a different platform (Realm). Secondly, HTML, CSS and JavaScript are all textual and you can easily store text in [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/?authuser=0). Third, *Firebase* has no files; it's a NoSQL database that uses a parent/child structure with no pre-defined schema. [Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/?authuser=0) may be a good solution if you have files you want to store or even Cloud Firestore if you need more complex queries than Firebase will easily handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking is not possible.

But what you can do is save temporarily  whatever code in a file locally, upload the file to firebase storage and then delete the local file. The user will not even know that for a few seconds you are saved the file locally.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Is there any chance I could store the contents of the file to a database, then write that to the device?

Comment: Well that depends. Theoretically you could use firebase storage or firestore and have as key the file name and as value the contents but the issue you might face is character limit and characters that aren't allowed. See here for more info:https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits and https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I appreciate it.